# Иконки необходимо отцентрировать и выровнять по высоте(все 150px;), расположить их над тесктом. При использовании display: flex; картинки смещаются

Tags: css, html5, flexbox

Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться. Повторяю урок по видео, у лектора этот код работает- у меня нет. Несколько раз проверила написание построчно. Результат должен быть как на картинке. Спасибо! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import "reset.css";
body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1140px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-line {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 150px;
}

header {
  background-color: #87509c;
}

.header-nav {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.header-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

.header-nav ul li {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: background 300ms ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.header-nav ul li.active {
  background: #643a79;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.header-nav ul li:hover {
  background: #643a79;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: background 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.bottom-line {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 85px;
  padding-bottom: 145px;
}

.bottom-line p {
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 48px;
  color: #f7f3ea;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  background: #eb7d4b;
  height: 65px;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #c86a40;
  transition: background 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #c86a40;
  transition: background 300ms ease-in-out;
}

section.services {
  background: #17c2a4;
  padding: 120px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

section.services h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

section.services h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 86px;
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -43px;
  bottom: 0;
}

section.services .description {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

section.services .services_list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

section.services .services_list .service_item {
  width: calc(25% - 15px);
}

section.services .services_list .service_item .img {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Наш урок по CSS</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="top-line">
        <a href="https://geniuscourses.com" title="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
        <nav class="header-nav">
          <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-line">
        <p>Hi there! We are the new kids on the block<br /> and we build awesome websites and mobile apps.</p>
        <a href="https://geniuscourses.com" class="button">WORK WITH US!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="services">
    <div class="wrepper">

      <h2>SERVICES WE PROVIDE</h2>
      <p class="description">We are working with both individuals and businesses from all over the globe<br />to create awesome websites and applications.</p>
      <div class="services_list">
        <div class="service_item">

          <div class="img">
            <img src="images/icon1.png" alt="icon">
            <h3 class="item_title">Branding</h3>
            <p class="item_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_item">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="images/icon2.png" alt="icon">
            <h3 class="item_title">Branding</h3>
            <p class="item_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_item">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="images/icon3.png" alt="icon">
            <h3 class="item_title">Branding</h3>
            <p class="item_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="service_item">
          <div class="img">
            <img src="images/icon4.png" alt="icon">
            <h3 class="item_title">Branding</h3>
            <p class="item_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>



















</body>

</html>
```

Comment: блоку с классом `img` нужно дописать `flex-direction: column`

Comment: Спасибо! Решила всё куда проще.

Answer (score 0):

```css
section.services .services_list .service_item .img {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="services_list">
  <div class="service_item">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="images/icon1.png" alt="icon">
    </div>
    <h3 class="item_title">Branding</h3>
    <p class="item_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ошибка была в HTML документе. div class="img" должен содержать только файл с картонкой, а у меня в нём ещё заголовок и параграф были. Перенесла заголовок и параграф в div class="service_item" и всё заработало! Правильно говорят- Сначала проверь/попробуй всё сам, потом беги на форум плакать.